# Airflow - Some times DAG is not starting

Tags: airflow

When I run manually, sometimes DAG is not getting started. It is showing tasks's staus as 'no status' only. Then I am manually making each task as 'success' and restarting the airflow scheduler, webserver.

Can you please suggest/help me to get this solved?.

Thanks,

Samanth

Comment: can you post your dag's code for us please?

Comment: Please find more details here:

1. I have prepared DAG which is working very nicely.
2. After few days, the DAG has failed due to some database side changes (ex:- the task is defined using PostgresOperator). That is fine.
3. Now I have fixed database side issue. 
4. Now I ran DAG again. This time, the DAG ran until previously failed step and not running remaining steps  ( keep showing 'no status' )

Please let me know if need sample DAG also.

Thanks,
Samanth

Comment: Can you please help me?